# picking on matplotlib legend when legend is outside of axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've run across and interesting quirk when I've modified the legend_picking.py example where the legend is outside of the axes as follows:

```
#leg = ax.legend(loc='upper left', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
leg = ax.legend(loc='upper left', fancybox=True, shadow=True,bbox_to_anchor=(.95,0.95))
```

The onpick function ends up being called twice for the Line2D artist that I click on in the legend.  I think this has to do with the fact that the children "tree" of the legend has the lines twice.  Once, in the children of the box packers and secondly, as the children of the legend's lines list.

My work around was to modify the onpick routine as follows:

```
def onpick(event):
  # on the pick event, find the orig line corresponding to the
  # legend proxy line, and toggle the visibility

  # prevent double pick of same artist all on the same mouseevent
  if onpick.lastevent!=event.mouseevent:
    onpick.artistsdone=[]
  if onpick.lastevent==event.mouseevent and event.artist in onpick.artistsdone:
    return
  onpick.lastevent=event.mouseevent        # save off the mouseevent
  onpick.artistsdone.append(event.artist)  # mark this artist as serviced
  legline = event.artist
  origline = lined[legline]
  vis = not origline.get_visible()
  origline.set_visible(vis)
  # Change the alpha on the line in the legend so we can see what lines
  # have been toggled
  if vis:
      legline.set_alpha(1.0)
  else:
      legline.set_alpha(0.2)
  fig.canvas.draw()
onpick.lastevent=None
onpick.artistsdone=[]
```

My questions:  Can someone think of a more elegant way of dealing with this?
  and, Can you think of a situation where I won't get the behavior I expect?

Comment: maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278358/double-event-registered-on-mouse-click-if-legend-is-outside-axes

Comment: It is odd how both you and @dhara hit the same problem at almost the same time.  Sorry, I didn't read your OP carefully enough the first time, should have done the linking the other way.

Comment: This should be fixed on the master branch