# Matplotlib legend picking with anchored

Tags: matplotlib, legend

I am doing something like this http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/legend_picking.html 
However i change the legend position to 
 `leg = ax.legend(loc='center left',bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5),fancybox=True, shadow=True)`

The the clicking event is not handle by the program anymore, when I click on the legend it will not toggle on or off.

Answer (score 0):

Get the answer, its not working due to the bug that the onlick event run 2 times when it is outside the plot.
More detail answer and solution can be found in [Double event registered on mouse-click if legend is outside axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278358/double-event-registered-on-mouse-click-if-legend-is-outside-axes)